# Get middle line from the output of a command

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, pipe

The following command list the duration of I-frames present in a video file.

```
ffprobe -i ./test.mp4 -v quiet -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v:0 -of flat -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time | awk -F'=' '{gsub(/"/, "", $NF); print $NF}'
```

I'm trying to get the duration of I-frame that is in middle. The output of the above command will be like

```
0.066667
2.066667
4.066667
9.066667
14.066667
19.066667
24.066667
```

How do I get the middle value? Here, I would like to get `9.066667` as the result. If the number of lines is even (say I've 2 values), I need to get the 1st value.

I tried using `wc` to get the number of lines and `sed` to print the middle line. But, this straightforward solution required me to run the command twice. I tried piping the command, but I didn't find any solution for storing the value in a variable (from the `wc` command) and using the same in another command (`sed` command) while retaining the piped output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {print a[int((NR+1)/2)]}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working correctly if the number of rows is odd. This approach gives me the result as `4.066667` while I'm expecting `9.066667`. Modified this to `awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {print a[int((NR+1)/2)]}'` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

@**Kishore** : if the input isn't too big, e.g. `< 50 MB`, just load it all at once, then follow the same idea as **WilliamPursell's** solution, with a minor modication :

> ```
> mawk 'END { print $(int( (NF + (_ < $NF) ) / 2 )) }' FS='\n' RS='^$'
> ```

- *due to the fact, by and large, inputs come with a trailing new line, only add the extra `+1` whenever there isn't one

  — `(_ < $NF)` checks whether `$NF` is greater than an empty string, i.e. `$NF` contains stuff, which is only true when there isn't a trailing newline

|

```
jot 4 | gtee >( gcat -n >&2 ) | gcat - | 

mawk 'END { print $(int((NF+(_<$NF))/2)) }' FS='\n' RS='^$' 
     1  1
     2  2
     3  3
     4  4
2

jot 5 | gtee >( gcat -n >&2 ) | gcat - | 

mawk 'END { print $(int((NF+(_<$NF))/2)) }' FS='\n' RS='^$'
3
     1  1
     2  2
     3  3
     4  4
     5  5
```

Comment: It is most probable that the output from the command won't have a trailing new line. Anyway, this seems to be a better approach in extreme cases.